# Animation iteration delay CSS3

Tags: css, animation

Is there a way to add a delay between each iteration?

EX: I want to add a first delay of 2s and an interation delay of 10s

Here is some code:

Code:

```
/* PROCESSAR AQUI! */
/*...*/


/* KEYFRAMES */

@-webkit-keyframes transitdescription {
    15%     { margin-left: 45px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes transitimage {
    0%      { right: -100%;}
    10%     { right: -webkit-calc(93% - 350px);}
    25%    { right: -webkit-calc(90% - 350px);}
    90%    { right: -webkit-calc(90% - 350px);}
    100%    { right: -webkit-calc(200%);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotateimg {
    50%  {-webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes pluswidth {
    50%  {  width: 450px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes leaveimage {
    50%  {  width: 450px;}
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Whats an interation? I'm guessing either iteration or interaction?

Comment: Iteration*
Now I'm using a javascript that remove and adds the class every x seconds

Comment: So when the page loads you want to wait 2 seconds then animate, then when the animation has finished you want to wait ten seconds then animate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS animation delay in repeating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13887889/css-animation-delay-in-repeating)

Answer (score 4):

There isn't such a property, although [it has been suggested](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2011May/0549.html).

There are workarounds:

```
@-webkit-keyframes transitimage {
    /* animation here */
    10%, 100% { /* wait for 10 seconds without doing anything */ }
}
```

which is far from ideal.
You can see this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13887889/css-animation-delay-in-repeating) for other workarounds.