# Delay between CSS Animation with 0.1s duration

Tags: css, animation

i have a little issue with the css animation and keyframe feature...

i have a little monster with blinking eyes... the eyes should blink just 0.1s

And then i want to have a duration... and then the animation should loop.
This is my animation/keyframe:

```
@keyframes blinkingEyes {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);    
  }
  36% {
    transform: rotateX(90deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(90deg);
  }
}
```

And this is my animation property:

```
animation: blinkingEyes 0.15s 1s infinite linear;
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/TorbenG/y1q1ht2j/4/)

I found a workaround with a x% between my start and end value. But nothing works for me.. i hope you could help me

Comment: I think that's all you can really do.  Animation delay only affects how long it takes for the animation to kick off.  See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13927380/854246.  You're going to have to bake your delay into the animation itself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS animation delay in repeating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13887889/css-animation-delay-in-repeating)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need several keyframes for this, and then make the animation run infinite times.

See:

```css
#monster {
    margin-top: 60px;
    height: 93px;
    width: 75px;
    border-radius: 120px;
    background: yellow;
    /* text-align: center; */
    position: relative;
}
    

.eye {
  height: 12px;
  width: 8px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 30px; 
  float: left;
  animation: blinkingEyes 1.5s linear infinite;
}

.eyeLeft {  
  margin-left: 18px;  
}

.eyeRight {
    margin-left: 22px;
}

.mouth {
    font-weight: 900;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    /* display: inline-block; */
    width: 5px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 20px;
    /* text-align: center; */
    /* left: 47%; */
    position: absolute;
    top: 47px;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    left: 35px;
}

@keyframes blinkingEyes {
  0%, 97%, 100% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);    
  }
  98%, 99% {
    transform: rotateX(90deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="monster">
  <div class="monsterBody">  
    <div class="eye eyeLeft"> 
    </div>
    <div class="eye eyeRight">    
    </div>
    <div class="mouth">
      )
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Must be much cooler if to only blink with one eye ;) ... plus 1