# Using Javascript to Start CSS Animation at Certain Percent

Tags: javascript, css, animation

Let's say I have a simple and linear CSS animation like this

```
@keyframes move {
    0% {top: 0;}
    100% {top: -10000px;} 
}
```

Which loops infinitly, and uses 10 steps:

```
.move {
    animation: move 1s steps(10, end) infinite;
    animation-play-state: running;
}
```

And it has a second animation which makes it go for 60 seconds

```
.sixty_seconds {animation-duration: 60s;}
```

How can I use javascript to start the animation halfway through its iteration?  Is there a way to start a specific animation at a specific percent through its iteration?  I need this starting point to be programmable, as it could start at 30% one time, or 77.32% the next.

I'm sure the answer is right under my nose, but I can't seem to find anything that gets it to use these existing animations starting at a specific point.

Thank you very much.

Comment: [`animation-delay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-delay).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS animation delay in repeating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13887889/css-animation-delay-in-repeating)

Comment: That seems to work fairly well when using something like item.style.animationDelay = "-"+seconds+"s";

Comment: I did not know animation-delay did anything except for wait for an animation to begin.

Comment: Although this does not allow for a certain position easily does it, if I call the same function at -500s do I have to account for time elapsed in the previous animations?

Comment: It does help me get a certain starting position, however. But how could I use this to change to a specific position of the animation on the fly.